# tooltip pointer is showing downwards to the left of the hyper link

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have used tipsy tooltip plugin. I want to display the tooltip to the left of the link.I have used the following code.
Tooltip points to the link to its left correctly. But the problem is its pointer is not pointing to the link. It is pointing downwards. How to solve this issue?

JS / HTML

```
$('.tip').tipsy({gravity: 'e'});

<a class='tip' href='index.php' title='test'>Test</a>

(function($) {
$.fn.tipsy = function(options) {

    options = $.extend({}, $.fn.tipsy.defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {

        var opts = $.fn.tipsy.elementOptions(this, options);

        $(this).hover(function() {

            $.data(this, 'cancel.tipsy', true);

            var tip = $.data(this, 'active.tipsy');
            if (!tip) {
                tip = $('<div class="tipsy lefttip"><div class="tipsy-inner"/></div>');
                tip.css({position: 'absolute', zIndex: 100000});
                $.data(this, 'active.tipsy', tip);

            }

            if ($(this).attr('title') || typeof($(this).attr('original-title')) != 'string') {
                $(this).attr('original-title', $(this).attr('title') || '').removeAttr('title');
            }

            var title;
            if (typeof opts.title == 'string') {
                title = $(this).attr(opts.title == 'title' ? 'original-title' : opts.title);
            } else if (typeof opts.title == 'function') {
                title = opts.title.call(this);
            }

            tip.find('.tipsy-inner')[opts.html ? 'html' : 'text'](title || opts.fallback);

            var pos = $.extend({}, $(this).offset(), {width: this.offsetWidth, height: this.offsetHeight});
            tip.get(0).className = 'tipsy'; // reset classname in case of dynamic gravity
            tip.remove().css({top: 0, left: 0, visibility: 'hidden', display: 'block'}).appendTo(document.body);
            var actualWidth = tip[0].offsetWidth, actualHeight = tip[0].offsetHeight;
            var gravity = (typeof opts.gravity == 'function') ? opts.gravity.call(this) : opts.gravity;

            switch (gravity.charAt(0)) {
                case 'n':
                    tip.css({top: pos.top + pos.height, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2}).addClass('tipsy-north');
                    break;
                case 's': 
                    tip.css({top: pos.top - actualHeight, left: pos.left + pos.width / 2 - actualWidth / 2}).addClass('tipsy-south');
                    break;
                case 'e': 
                    tip.css({top: (pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2)+5, left: pos.left - actualWidth}).addClass('tipsy-east');
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    tip.css({top: pos.top + pos.height / 2 - actualHeight / 2, left: pos.left + pos.width}).addClass('tipsy-west');
                    break;
            }

            if (opts.fade) {
                tip.css({opacity: 0, display: 'block', visibility: 'visible'}).animate({opacity: 0.8});
            } else {
                tip.css({visibility: 'visible'});
            }

        }, function() {
            $.data(this, 'cancel.tipsy', false);
            var self = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                if ($.data(this, 'cancel.tipsy')) return;
                var tip = $.data(self, 'active.tipsy');
                if (opts.fade) {
                    tip.stop().fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });
                } else {
                    //tip.remove();
                }
            }, 100);

        });

    });

};

// Overwrite this method to provide options on a per-element basis.
// For example, you could store the gravity in a 'tipsy-gravity' attribute:
// return $.extend({}, options, {gravity: $(ele).attr('tipsy-gravity') || 'n' });
// (remember - do not modify 'options' in place!)
$.fn.tipsy.elementOptions = function(ele, options) {
    return $.metadata ? $.extend({}, options, $(ele).metadata()) : options;
};

$.fn.tipsy.defaults = {
    fade: false,
    fallback: '',
    gravity: 'n',
    html: false,
    title: 'title'
};

$.fn.tipsy.autoNS = function() {
    return $(this).offset().top > ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height() / 2) ? 's' : 'n';
};

$.fn.tipsy.autoWE = function() {
    return $(this).offset().left > ($(document).scrollLeft() + $(window).width() / 2) ? 'e' : 'w';
};

})(jQuery);
```

CSS

```
.tipsy { 
    margin-top:-5px!important;
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-image: url(../images/btn/tip.png)!important; 
}
.tipsy-inner { 
    vertical-align:middle;
    padding: 8px 12px; 
    -moz-border-radius:3px; 
    -webkit-border-radius:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
    background-color: #3a3333; 
    color: white; 
    max-width: 200px; 
    text-align: center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:12px; 
}
.tipsy-north { 
    background-position: top center; 
}
.tipsy-south { 
    background-position: bottom center; 
}
.tipsy-east { 
    background-position: right center; 
}
.tipsy-west { 
    background-position: left center; 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "its pointer... pointing downwards"? also pls provide the html code you're using!

Comment: i am here mentioned arrow as a pointer.

Comment: so you get a downwards arrow instead of the standard pointer? not sure, something else might be interfering with it or your computer's default mouse pointer is that arrow... could be anything, you're not providing too much details...

Comment: dynamically display the arrow image to point rightside when the tooltip is showing to the left of the link. likewise when i display the tooltip to the right of the link, arrow should be displayed to point leftside and viceversa...

Comment: ah, so you mean the triangle that's supposed to show towards the link when the tooltip appears, right?

Comment: yes right. I want to display it dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most probably with the image you're using in `.tipsy`

I tried with the following and it's working fine:

```
.tipsy { 
    margin-top:-5px!important;
    padding: 5px; 
    font-size: 10px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  
    background-image: url('http://www.laurafeld.com/2010-In-the-woods/Images/20px-TriangleArrow-Right.svg.png')!important;
    // above just an example image I grabbed from a quick search
}
```

**[HERE IS A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wpQ89/)**

**EDIT:** After I saw your recent edit, I understand you want to generate that image dynamically, so I'd suggest you remove `background-image` from `.tipsy` and add a different image to each of `.tipsy-east`, `.tipsy-west`... as follows:

```
.tipsy-north { 
    background-position: top center; 
    background-image: url('/images/path/down_arrow.jpg')!important;
}
.tipsy-south { 
    background-position: bottom center; 
    background-image: url('/images/path/up_arrow.jpg')!important;
}
.tipsy-east { 
    background-position: right center; 
    background-image: url('/images/path/right_arrow.jpg')!important;
}
.tipsy-west { 
    background-position: left center; 
    background-image: url('/images/path/left_arrow.jpg')!important;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wpQ89/2/)**

**NOTE:** The images I used are not realy ones, you will have to create / grab yours for each direction and add them.

Comment: when i set gravity to e the arrow should point towards right and when i set it to s the arrow should point towards down. likewise i dynamically need the arrow indication position.